# React native center image in ImageBackground

Tags: react-native

react-native how to center the image on ImageBackground

I have simple code like this

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <ImageBackground source={require('../../../public/images/sss.png')} style={styles.image}>
  <Image 
      style={styles.logoStyle}
      source={require('./../../../public/images/logo1.png')}
      />
  </ImageBackground>
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center"
  },

  logoStyle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

The issue is my image which is inside ImageBackground showing on the left of the screen I need to center it

Comment: reiszeMode: "cover"  OR  resizeMode : center => https://reactnative.dev/docs/image-style-props

Answer (score 1):

Align your image which is inside ImageBackground to the center like below it will work.

```
  image: {
    flex: 1,
    resizeMode: "cover",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: 'center',
  }
```